# ASWebAuthenticationSession: Support own provider

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, aswebauthenticationsession

My company has a couple of apps and would like to use it's own SSO service instead of using a public like google or facebook.

For SSO we would like to use ASWebAuthenticationSession. What are the requirements to that SSO service to work with ASWebAuthenticationSession? I could not find the relevant information on apple.com

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: It is working with every OAuth Provider. Really simple to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working with every OAuth Provider. Really simple to use.